# Up/Down picture by mouse hover

Tags: javascript, css

I want something like picture links in bottom of [this](http://andishkadeh.ir/) site.Any body know whats the effect of the site or please suggest to me some javascript code example or library to make picture up/down on mouse hover and make some beautiful *tooltip* too.

Comment: Could you specify a little bit more of what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need CSS, and on hover change the margin:

```
img {
    margin-bottom: -75px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    -webkit-transition: margin 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: margin 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: margin 0.5s ease;
    transition: margin 0.5s ease;
}

img:hover {
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

This code is basically copied from the site you've provided. I would be careful by using it as is. Take it only as an example.

Comment: Thank you,But what about tooltip ?